# Split any word starting with uppercase and every digit at the end

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

How can I split (in java) every word (separated by an uppercase) and the digits at the end of the string using regex f.ex.:

1. HouseCat22
2. wolf1
3. thisIsTheEnd15

For 1) I need an array of 3 elements:

```
House
Cat
22
```

For 2) I need an array of 2 elements:

```
Wolf
1
```

For 3) It should split as 5 elements:

```
this
Is
The
End
15
```

I've been trying for hours without success ... but I simply don't get.
The following splits the words:
`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
but I have no clue how to split the number(s) at the end of line.

I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks a lot!
Didier

Comment: You can split the words with just `(?=[A-Z])`

Comment: @Didier, please check the 2 solutions (I removed one for the time being) and please let know if either works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the number matching pattern to the positive lookahead:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9A-Z])
              ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IjAr3m/2). However, this solution will not split between the uppercase letters and digits (so, `EndD15` will be split in `End` and `D15`).

You may consider a *matching* approach (it will be more efficient and readable), you may use

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/IjAr3m/4).

This will match:

- `[a-zA-Z][a-z]*` - any ASCII letter and then any 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits.

This may be further adjusted as the requirements evolve. Sample [Java code](http://ideone.com/t9GbGZ):

```
String s = "thisIsTheEnd15";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+").matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group(0));
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [this, Is, The, End, 15]
```

Comment: Requiring a lowercase letter to come before wouldn't work if the previous word was one letter long, like `A` or `I`.

Comment: @4castle: Each of the three solutions is different, but enough for the provided examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think that's just because it's an edge case OP hadn't considered.

Comment: @Michael: The problem is that there are usually a lot of edge cases in this kind of scenarios.

Comment: @Michael: That is why I suggest a *matching* approach to consider, it is usually more flexible and can be adjusted to the requirements that were not evident before asking the question.

Comment: @Didier: So, splitting approach worked for you, right? I will add some code for the matching one then, just in case your requirements become too unwieldly for a splitting approach.

Comment: Little comment on the second "matching" approach: [a-zA-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+  This one doesn't seem to work in java.

Comment: @Didier: see the code and demo, it works very well. BTW, it works in a lot of languages, not only in Java.